# Duplicate rows because 1 column has multiple distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running a SELECT query to get data across multiple tables in the same server instance. However I've just noticed that the rows pulled on some data get duplicated because the main table I'm pulling from has a few different values in one of the columns. Here's the query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT BIF030.C_ACCOUNT AS ACCOUNTNUMBER,
    BIF003.C_ACCOUNTTYPE AS ACCOUNTTYPECODE,
    CON013.C_DESCRIPTION AS ACCOUNTTYPE,
    BIF003.C_DIVISION AS ZONE_DIVISONCODE,
    CON028.C_DESCRIPTION AS ZONE_DIVISION,
    BIF030.C_METER as METERNUMBER,
    BIF005.C_METERCUSTOM1 AS REGISTERNUMBER,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,2), BIF030.N_CONSUMP) AS CONSUMPTION,       
    CON007.C_DESCRIPTION AS UNITS,       
    BIF030.T_READDATE AS READINGDATE,
    MONTH(BIF030.T_READDATE) AS READINGMONTH,
    DAY(BIF030.T_READDATE) AS READINGDAY,
    YEAR(BIF030.T_READDATE) AS READINGYEAR,
    BIF030.I_DAYS AS READINGDAYSCOUNT
    
      FROM ADVANCED.BIF030     
        LEFT JOIN ADVANCED.CON007 ON CON007.C_UNITS=BIF030.C_UNITS
        LEFT JOIN ADVANCED.BIF005 ON BIF005.C_METER=BIF030.C_METER
        LEFT JOIN ADVANCED.BIF003 ON BIF003.C_ACCOUNT=BIF030.C_ACCOUNT
        LEFT JOIN ADVANCED.CON013 ON CON013.C_ACCOUNTTYPE=BIF003.C_ACCOUNTTYPE
        LEFT JOIN ADVANCED.CON028 ON CON028.C_DIVISION=BIF003.C_DIVISION
        
    WHERE T_READDATE > '01-01-2014'
    
    ORDER BY ACCOUNTNUMBER, READINGDATE ASC
```

I know SELECT DISTINCT is frowned upon, but I get even more rows without it.  Here's a sample of what the data looks like when pulled:

| ACCOUNTNUMBER | ACCOUNTTYPECODE | ACCOUNTTYPE | ZONE_DIVISIONCODE | ZONE_DIVISION | METERNUMBER | REGISTERNUMBER | CONSUMPTION | UNITS | READINGDATE | READINGMONTH | READINGDAY | READINGYEAR | READINGDAYSCOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | SP | ACCOUNT TYPE 1 | 00 | 00-NO ZONE | 123456789 | 987654321 | 3.00 | Thousands of Gallons | 2014-01-16 00:00:00.00 | 1 | 16 | 2014 | 30 |
| 1234567 | MF | ACCOUNT TYPE 2 | 02 | 02-GRAVITY | 123456789 | 987654321 | 3.00 | Thousands of Gallons | 2014-01-16 00:00:00.00 | 1 | 16 | 2014 | 30 |
| 1234567 | SR | ACCOUNT TYPE 3 | 02 | 02-GRAVITY | 123456789 | 987654321 | 3.00 | Thousands of Gallons | 2014-01-16 00:00:00.00 | 1 | 16 | 2014 | 30 |

I also know the column that is messing this up is the "AccountTypeCode" because other accounts that don't have multiple codes associated with the "AccountNumber" only show 1 set of rows. So this one specifically (and probably others) is tripling the amount of rows pulled when it should only pull one for each "ReadingDate".

Also if anyone knows a good way to optimize the query I'd be happy to learn. I know just enough SQL to be dangerous, but not enough to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Always when you want to shrink down multiple records into one you have to know the rule you want to use do that. You have 3 different AccountTypeCode - which one do you want?

Comment: So I guess I should add that in an ideal result the 'AccountTypeCode' would correlate to the associated 'ReadingDate'. It's hard to explain without going in depth, but basically the "AccountNumber" will always be the same, but the "AccountTypeCode" can change. However the 'ReadingDate' will always only be associated with a specific "AccountTypeCode".

Comment: Include sample data and desired results in your question to help illustrate your issue and make it easier and possible to assist.

Comment: I attached a photo of the results (shrunk down to 3 rows, it actually pulls 200), but I had to link it (it's not embeded) since my account is new. As for the expected results I should only be showing 1 of the 3 rows pictured, not all 3.
EDIT:
In this case the "Single Family Res Inside" row is the only row it should show, but instead it shows the 3 rows in the linked picture.

Comment: Edited the post to use a Markdown table for the results. In this table the type 1 is the only one that should show

Comment: So I do need it for this one. I'm currently using this query to create a table for use in a different program. That's part of what's making this frustrating. And the data is fragmented so that table is the only one that has ACCOUNTTYPE in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So good news and I want to add this in case it helps anyone else in the future. I found out that since the `ACCOUNTTYPECODE` and `ZONE_DIVISIONCODE` were coming from the table `BIF003` I needed to add more in the `WHERE` statement. This is what fixed it for me:

```
AND BIF030.C_CUSTOMER = BIF003.C_CUSTOMER
```

Because the `C_CUSTOMER` column was different (it's a column in the `BIF003` and `BIF030` tables) which lead to the separate `ACCOUNTTYPECODE` results I need to check it in the `WHERE` statement.

Thanks everyone for kick starting my brain on this one.